# Arrangement of input fields

Tags: usability, forms, input-fields

I have a form where I ask the user for data. I want the user to give me his name, email id and phone number. On mobile UI I have two options.

One: I design conventional interface with all three fields on the form and submit button. Two: I design 3 cards like the design on the screen. Each card asks for one detail and next card appear when the user submits that particular detail and can be swiped back if want to change the detail in the previous card and main submit button on the last card.

Which design you guys think it is better?

Answer (score 3):

So you're thinking between choosing a single field form (so multiple steps) or a single step form.  I'd go with option 1, single step form.

> The general idea behind multiple-step forms is that the further the
>   prospect goes down the sales funnel, the less likely they are to turn
>   around when asked for valuable information. Essentially, they’re more
>   likely to finish the whole form because they’re already committed.
>   Basically, people like filling out longer forms when they’re already
>   invested in the process, like during checkout while shopping online.

This works because you're clustering fields into chunks that relate to one another.

> They do not work well if you don’t have the form’s progress clearly
>   listed somewhere. It’s important to make sure that you provide the
>   user with constant feedback on their progress to let them know how
>   much more time they will require to finish the form.

If you put this in a card format, you do not communicate properly what they can expect next. It requires more effort both mentally and physically to fill in a form that requires this much interaction.

You don't really ask for enough information to warrant a multi-step form. The whole charm of having multiple steps is that you ease users into letting go of more sensitive information in each step, while keeping them engaged through having committed so much already. With only three fields, I'd pick a single form.

More about multi-step forms: http://blog.formkeep.com/should-you-use-single-step-or-multi-step-forms/

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important steps of improving usability is:

### Reduce the number of clicks

Your second option with *each field in a card* unnecessarily adds clicks/taps.

You form is small enough to be appropriate for a single pager. Go with option 1.

**Keep all the fields on the same screen**